# Boot SSD unboots itself

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd

I have noticed that every months, my SSD (which I used a my booting HD) stops working and I need to format it.

The computer cannot boot and I get the error message, please insert bootable device.
Is this a virus or something is wrong with my SSD settings?

Comment: Bugs in the SSD firmware causing data loss.  Contact your manufacturer to see if they have a fix.

Comment: You could also see if there is a firmware update for the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Please Insert Bootable device tells you only one thing, that the boot process cannot hand off to bootable media.

It could be the boot sequence changed, a file has been corrupted, or a drive is dying.

That this happens repeatedly indicates a hard ware issue.

The best place to start is with the SSD manufacturer. Download their diagnostic utility and test the drive. While you are on the manufacturers site, search their forums for similar issues and resolutions and firmware updates for the SSDs.

If the SSD fails diagnostics, or their is a trend on their forums try contacting the manufacturer for a repair or replacement.